# How to create a "open file" hotkey in Sublime in mac?

Tags: sublimetext3, hotkeys

I am using Sublime 3.2.2 on macOS. I looked in my user settings and key bindings and I don't see where the hotkey for opening a new file in sublime is set. How can I set this?

Comment: Command + O will prompt you to open a file?

Comment: @0stone0 No, I tried this (this is the indeed the hotkey on my other macbook), but it doesn't work for some reason. Nothing happens when I press it.